# I need some software that has a continuous page to draw on

Tags: software-recommendation, canvas

I have a project which has many steps and I'd like to create a visual representation of the steps in a flowchart form, but the chart will be very long. I need something that I can "draw" on that will continue without "paging". I simply need an extremely long canvas.

Does anyone know of software that will do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How long? Illustrator can do 16300 pt high stuff. since it can zoom in by 400% easily that's  a lot of pixels lot more than illustrator can safely export in on go. Longest flowchart that i ever made with graphWiz was about 37 meters long in final hard copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For flowcharts maybe give yed a try. It is a node based graph editor. You can connect the nodes and label the connections. 
You can also export as SVG and many image files. It has a never ending canvas like you want.

The yed graph editor can be downloaded [here](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed)

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks so much. This is exactly what I need. I can't believe something like this exists. I wish I could give you more points for this answer. AND ITS FREE!!!!!!! UNBELIEVABLE!

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/) is what you're looking for.

A quick preview:

[image: draw.io example]

As you can see it's just a simple, intuitive browser tool. It's got some handy features like copy and pasting cell styles, forcing objects to front/back and toggling pages on or off. If you need there are also plenty of tutorials and instructions to be found online though I have to admit it's extremely straight forward. :)

I find it useful for speedy flowcharts but would still bounce back to Indesign or Illustrator for anything heavier.

There are a few similar sites compared [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/diagramly/) if this one doesn't do the trick for you.

Comment: This is an interesting option.

Answer (score 1):

Hum... MyPaint http://mypaint.org/ has an "infinite canvas" philosophy. You can simply zoom out or pan and you have more space.

But potentially you have the wrong approach.

A decent vector program like Illustrator, Corel Draw, Afinity Designer or Inkscape can:

1. Have a quite big canvas.
2. Draw and scale objects to a very tiny size, and zoom in again.
3. Move around objects so they fit better your needs.

In my opinion, you should use a program that **let you organize your work**, **inclusive using layers**, rather than "drawing freely in the wild".

Comment: I need something like a web page that I can draw on that just scrolls down as long as there is content to be seen.

Comment: @user2721815 in that case how would you add stuff below that what is seen?